# how to assign an attribute value to another attribute in a different Node in xslt 2.0

Tags: xslt

Can anyone help me out on my below requirement. the id attribute value "123" will be assigned to attribute ref="123" in node "cd11" . Thanks, in advance

### Input XML

```
<publisher>
    <Name id="123">
        <Location>Chicago</Location>
    </Name>
    <catalogue id="111" >
        <cd11 id="222">
            <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
            <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
            <year>1985</year>
        </cd11>
    </catalogue>
</publisher>
```

### Output XML

```
<publisher>
    <Name id="123">
        <Location>Chicago</Location>
    </Name>
    <catalogue id="111" >
        <cd11 id="222" ref="123">
            <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
            <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
            <year>1985</year>
        </cd11>
    </catalogue>
</publisher>
```

Transform :
Create a new attribute "ref" in node "cd11" and the attribute @Name/id will be assigned to @cd11/ref

Comment: Post XSL codes you have tried so far

Answer (score 1):

This is one possible way :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="catalogue/cd11">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="ref">
          <xsl:value-of select="parent::catalogue/preceding-sibling::Name/@id"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

- `<xsl:template match="@* | node()">...` : Identity template. This template copies all nodes and attributes where it is applied to to the output XML, unchanged.
- `<xsl:template match="catalogue/cd11">...` : This template overrides identity template for `<cd11>` element that is direct child of `<catalogue>` parent. This template copies matched `cd11` elements and create new attribute `ref` which value taken from `id` attribute of 'preceding' `Name` element.

Answer (score 1):

first, I suppose that   by @Name/id and  @cd11/ref, you mean attribute "id" of  element "name" and attribute "ref" of  element "cd11",  which would  be Name/@id and cd11/@ref respectively

try the following
- create a  template for  the "cd11" with an input  parameter for  the ref attribute value.
- create a template for the  "catalogue" element, and within in it  call  template for "cd11" passing on the value  of the ref attribute ,  which is  extracted from  the sibling element "name"

...like so  ( may need to  edit before  compiling )

```
<xsl:stylesheet > 
 <!-- ...-->
 <xsl:template match="catalogue" >
   <!--   any other  processing of  catalogue element --> 

     <xsl:element name="catalogue">
        <xsl:attribute name="id" select="./@id"

       <!--  call the  cd11 template --> 
       <xsl:apply-templates select="./cd11">
          <xsl:param name="pRef" select="../name[1]/@id"
       </xsl:apply-templates>

     </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cd11" >
    <xsl:param name="pRef" />

    <xsl:element name="cd11" >
        <xsl:attribute name="id" select="./@id"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="ref" select="$pRef"/>
       <!-- copy  the body of the element--> 
        <xsl:copy-of select= "./*"/>
   </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>


<!-- ...-->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

hope it works out.